# Why upload data from ServletContext prevents loading servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I inject in Servlet Context object for working with DB. I use my implementation `ServletContextListener`. But when I try to use my servlet then get `HTTP Status [500] – [Internal Server Error]`.

My `ServletContextListener`:

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

        final ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();

        servletContext.setAttribute("db", new DBJointHandler("database_scripts", "authentication_database"));

    }
    ...
}
```

And my servlet:

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DBJoint db = (DBJoint) getServletContext().getAttribute("db");

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        db.somethingToDo();
        ...
    }
}
```

And at the time of the call `AddUserServlet` :

```
HTTP Status [500] – [Internal Server Error]

Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [ru.pravvich.servlets.AddUserServlet]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [ru.pravvich.servlets.AddUserServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
    ru.pravvich.servlets.AddUserServlet.<init>(AddUserServlet.java:18)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This occurs only at the time of the calling Servlet through browser form. If i cleaning up `(DBJoint) getServletContext().getAttribute("DB")` servlet work without issue. But I need this object for work with DB...

Why? What wrong? How fix this issue? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ServletContext is undefined during the construction of the servlet.

You need to defer initialising the `db` field until the servlet is being initialised:

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DBJoint db;

    @Override
    void init(ServletConfig config) {
        ServletContext servletContext = config.getServletContext();
        db = servletContext.getAttribute("db");
    }

    ...

}
```